# How GAE from Gcp scales regarding the java virtual machine memory usage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memory, google-cloud-platform

I am working in gcp and we have a large volume of data, my doubt is that I know that GAE scales horizontally creating new jvm instances and I suppose that Appserver instances are isolated and independent.There's no distributed shared memory or
anything like that.

But I am using collections to do some operations and at the end of the execution I noticed that the collections end with the total of records that were processed, which is strange because it seems that the jvms are sharing memory in some way, allowing me to use collections to store all the records processed, and they are not creating a new collection per each gae (jvm instance).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling has been implemented to keep your app's service up-to-speed with incoming requests. At any given time, your application can be running on one or many instances with requests being spread across all of them. There is no particular or special processing on one instance, differing from the other, as all of these spun up instances process requests. Your collections are processed as if by one and the only application, irrespective of how many instances are needed to run in parallel, to keep up with traffic. Related detail can be found on the "How Instances are Managed" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed).

Comment: Thanks, thats an interesting answer, sorry do you know how the instances share the memory between them, the objects, heap etc.

Comment: What is the scenario you are considering, when asking for sharing details? New instances are launched to serve traffic, so requests processed by one instance are not processed by another instance, which takes care of extra requests. If instance one processes a set of requests that differ from instance 2, there doesn't appear to be any need for resource sharing the way you contemplate. No information is stored on an instance, to make it differ from any other.

Comment: I juts want to understand how the is the process in which the instances share the collections memory as only one application and GAE doesn't create separate collections through the instances.

Comment: If you refer to Java Data Objects, persistence is implemented by means of the App Engine Datastore. Data stored this way is accessed by different instances using calls to Datastore, not local somehow shared memory. You may check [Defining Data Classes with JDO](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses) for related details.